# Trouble in getting error fixed in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell

I am pretty new to shell scripting and trying to learn it. However I am facing an error which i am not able to solve. Any help would really be appreciated.

```
$ FILE_List= $(ls merged_reads2/*/*join.fastq | sed ' :a ; {N;/\n/,/};ba')
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated address regex
```

and another one is

```
$ SAMPLE_LIST=$ (ls*fastq.gz| awk -F"_" '{print S1}' | sort | uniq | sed ':a ;{N;/\n/,/};ba')
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: With shell scripting, you have to be careful with quoting.  If you run `set -x` in your shell script, you should see what the shell sees and figure out your problem.

Comment: variable assignment **must** be of the form `var=value` with no spaces around the equal sign.

Comment: A useful resource is http://shellcheck.net which can help you with these kinds of syntax errors.